# Immutable js UpdateIn is storing number instead of object

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am trying to update a immutablejs object;

```
//action.vals = {element: "p", type: "text", content: "test", className: "paragraph-topic"}
return state
    .updateIn(['contents'], list => list.push(action.vals))         //<<<<<THis is failing
    .set('loading', false)
    .set('error', false)
  break;`
```

But instead it is storing `10` an integer .

I am really confused and i am in need of help suggestion.

[Here is my full code](https://gist.github.com/sidzan/5835aa26d819dafa1c1f279f16db237c)

Any help is much appreciated! I am going nuts due to lack of proper usage documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that on the `LOAD_DATA` reducer, you're setting `contents` to become an array instead of an immutable List:

```
case LOAD_DATA:
  return state
    .set('loading', true)
    .set('error', false)
    .setIn(['contents'], [])
```

This would cause quite a few problems. What's happening is that you're using the vanilla JS `push` function on your update, and that returns the `length` of the array. So I'm supposing `contents` has 10 elements?

You just need to change the `LOAD_DATA` reducer to have this instead:

`.setIn(['contents'], fromJS([]))`

or

`.setIn(['contents'], new List())`

If using `List()`, that has to be explicitly imported as well!

Comment: That solved my issue ! Thanks a lot for clear explanation !! Also i added `.updateIn(['contents'], list => [...list, action.vals])
` which fixed the remaining issue

Comment: What remaining issue? In fact, utilizing the `...` operator would spread your Immutable List to become an array again, and thus if you're accessing that List in a component through `get` or something similar, it would fail. You should stick to the same way you were doing before: `.updateIn(['contents'], list => list.push(action.vals))  `

Comment: if use `list.push(action.vals))`, it throws warning  as push is not a function. And it might be because ` case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .setIn(['contents'], action.data)
` uses a regular js.

Comment: If that's the case, you can still use `case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS: return state .setIn(['contents'], fromJS(action.data) `. You want that structure to be always the same, either an Immutable List or an array.

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this using `...`.

```
.updateIn(['contents'], list => [...list, action.vals])
```